# Show the last 3 clicked links in a php session

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to make a php session and show the last 3 clicked links on my website. I don't know what the best way is to do so.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Are you trying to save the last 3 clicks that a user has done on your site, specific to the user? Or are you attempting to record the last 3 clicks on your site from any user?

Comment: Yes that's corrert. Only for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because the array is small** you can do it like

```
<?php
function update(&$arr, $elem) {
  array_unshift($arr, $elem);
  array_pop($arr);
}
```

example

```
<?php
$arr = array(null,null,null);

update($arr, 'first');
update($arr, 'second');
update($arr, 'third');

print_r($arr);

update($arr, 'fourth');

print_r($arr);
```

As you can imagine you can do the same with an array in `$_SESSION`

```
$_SESSION['clicks'] = array(null, null, null);

update($_SESSION['clicks']);
```

If you want to implement the same behavior to bigger arrays you must optimize the array operations.